# k-means clustering using function 'kmeans' in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have this matrix:

```
x = [2+2*i 2-2*i -2+2*i -2-2*i];
```

I want to simulate transmitting it and adding noise to it. I represented the components of the complex number as below:

```
A = randn(150, 2) + 2*ones(150, 2); C = randn(150, 2) - 2*ones(150, 2);
```

At the receiver, I received the below vector, where the components are ordered based on what I sent originally, *i.e.*, the components of x).

```
X = [A A A C C A C C];
```

Now I want to apply the `kmeans(X)` to have four clusters, so `kmeans(X, 4)`. I am experiencing the following problems:

1. I am not sure if I can represent the complex numbers as shown in `X` above.
2. I can't plot the result of the `kmeans` to show the clusters.
3. I could not understand the clusters centroid results.
4. How can I find the best error rate, if this example was to represent a communication system and at the receiver, [*k*-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) was used in order to decide what the transmitted signal was?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't "understand" the cluster centroid results, then you don't understand how `k`-means works. I'll present a small summary here.

How *k*-means works is that for some data that you have, you want to group them into *k* groups.  You initially choose *k* random points in your data, and these will have labels from `1,2,...,k`.  These are what we call the **centroids**. Then, you determine how close the rest of the data are to each of these points.  You then group those points so that whichever points are closest to any of these *k* points, you assign those points to belong to that particular group (`1,2,...,k`).  After, for all of the points for each group, you update the **centroids**, which actually is defined as the representative point for each group.  For each group, you compute the average of all of the points in each of the *k* groups.  These become the **new** centroids for the next iteration.  In the next iteration,  you determine how close each point in your data is to **each of the centroids**.  You keep iterating and repeating this behaviour until the centroids don't move anymore, or they move very little.

---

Now, let's answer your questions one-by-one.

## 1. Complex number representation

`k`-means in MATLAB doesn't define how complex data is handled.  A common way for people to deal with complex numbered data is to split up the real and imaginary parts into separate dimensions as you have done.  This is a perfectly valid way to use `k`-means for complex valued data.

See this post on the MathWorks MATLAB forum for more details: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/78306

## 2. Plot the results

You aren't constructing your matrix `X` properly.  Note that `A` and `C` are both 150 x 2 matrices.  You need to structure `X` such that each **row** is a point, and each column is a variable.  Therefore, you need to concatenate your `A` and `C` **row-wise**.  Therefore:

```
X = [A; A; A; C; C; A; C; C];
```

Note that you have **duplicate points**.  This is actually no different than doing `X = [A; C];` as far as `kmeans` is concerned.  Perhaps you should generate `X`, then add the noise in rather than taking `A` and `C`, adding noise, then constructing your signal.

Now, if you want to plot the results as well as the centroids, what you need to do is use the **two output version** of `kmeans` like so:

```
[idx, centroids] = kmeans(X, 4);
```

`idx` will contain the cluster number that each point in `X` belongs to, and `centroids` will be a 4 x 2 matrix where each row tells you the mean of each cluster found in the data.  If you want to plot the data, as well as the clusters, you simply need to do following.  I'm going to loop over each cluster membership and plot the results on a figure.  I'm also going to colour in where the mean of each cluster is located:

```
x = X(:,1);
y = X(:,2);
figure;
hold on;
colors = 'rgbk';
for num = 1 : 4
    plot(x(idx == num), y(idx == num), [colors(num) '.']);
end

plot(centroids(:,1), centroids(:,2), 'c.', 'MarkerSize', 14);
grid;
```

The above code goes through each cluster, plots them in a different colour, then plots the centroids in cyan with a slightly larger thickness so you can see what the graph looks like.

This is what I get:

[image]

## 3. Understanding centroid results

This is probably because you didn't construct `X` properly.  This is what I get for my centroids:

```
centroids =

   -1.9176   -2.0759
    1.5980    2.8071
    2.7486    1.6147
    0.8202    0.8025
```

This is pretty self-explanatory and I talked about how this is structured earlier.

## 4. Best representation of the signal

What you can do is repeat the clustering a number of times, then the algorithm will decide what the best clustering was out of these times.  You would simply use the `Replicates` flag and denote how many times you want this run.  Obviously, the more times you run this, the better your results may be.  Therefore, do something like:

```
[idx, centroids] = kmeans(X, 4, 'Replicates', 5);
```

This will run `kmeans` 5 times and give you the best centroids of these 5 times.

Now, if you want to determine what the best sequence that was transmitted, you'd have to split up your `X` into 150 rows each (as your random sequence was 150 elements), then run a separate `kmeans` on each subset.  You can try to find the best representation of each part of the sequence by using the `Replicates` flag each time.... so you can do something like:

```
for num = 1 : 8
    %// Look at 150 points at a time
    [idx, centroids] = kmeans(X((num-1)*150 + 1 : num*150, :), 4, 'Replicates', 5);

    %// Do your analysis
    %//...
    %//...
end
```

`idx` and `centroids` would be the results for each portion of your transmitted signal.  You probably want to look at `centroids` at each iteration to determine what symbol was transmitted at a particular time.

---

If you want to plot the decision regions, then you're probably looking for a [Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram).  All you do is given a set of points that are defined within the domain of your problem, you just have to determine which cluster each point belongs to.  Given that our data spans between `-5 <= (x,y) <= 5`, let's go through each point in the grid and determine which cluster each point belongs to.  We'd then colour the appropriate point according to which cluster it belongs to.

Something like:

```
colors = 'rgbk';
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-5:0.05:5, -5:0.05:5);
X = X(:);
Y = Y(:);
figure;
hold on;
for idx = 1 : numel(X)
    [~,ind] = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus, [X(idx) Y(idx)], centroids).^2, 2));
    plot(X(idx), Y(idx), [colors(ind), '.']);
end
plot(centroids(:,1), centroids(:,2), 'c.', 'MarkerSize', 14);
```

---

The above code will plot the decision regions / Voronoi diagram of the particular configuration, as well as where the cluster centres are located.  Note that the code is rather unoptimized and it'll take a while for the graph to generate, but I wanted to write something quick to illustrate my point.

Here's what the decision regions look like:

[image]

---

Hope this helps!   Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Rayryeng. How can i determine the decision regions from this graph, and how can i find the bet error rate?

Comment: Can i consider the originally sent data as a training data and resend data again and consider it and a test data and use them to find the bet error rate?

Comment: @KawtherHamad - The decision regions are probably the Voronoi diagrams for the particular cluster configuration.  The **BIT** error rate is what you want to find?  All you have to do is extract out what the reconstructed sequence was, then do a point by point matching between the reconstructed signal and the original data, sum up the mismatches and divide by the total length of your sequence.  I won't do the BER because it's trivial, but I will do the Voronoi diagram for you.

Comment: I do appreciate your support :) when running the code, I am having this error: Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [. for the statement: [~,ind] = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus, [X(idx) Y(idx)], centroids).^2, 2));

Comment: @KawtherHamad forgot to add an end bracket. Did it in my end but forgot to add it here. I'll update

Comment: @KawtherHamad - I just checked.  the code is correct and it ran on my computer.  Try copying and pasting that entire code and do it again.

Comment: @KawtherHamad - What version of MATLAB do you have?  You may not be able to support the `~` statement.  If it's older than 2011, then do this instead:  `[dummy,ind] = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus, [X(idx) Y(idx)], centroids).^2, 2));`

Comment: Thank you. it is R2008b. I used the dummy instead of ~ and it worked fine.

Comment: @KawtherHamad - That's what I thought!  `~` with respect to function calls was introduced in more recent versions of MATLAB to discard unused output variables.  If you have an older version of MATLAB, you have to explicitly place these outputs in variables, even if you're not going to use them.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you rayryeng. Good luck to you too. Would not i be in need to send another data, i mean consider this data as trained data, and resend data as test data in order to find the bit error rate?

Comment: @KawtherHamad - Unfortunately this is as far as I go with regards to my knowledge in communication theory.  You're on your own :( sorry.  Good luck!

Comment: For the bit error rate, do you mean by the reconstructed sequence, the x and y. So would i compare those to X?

Comment: Does this code work for the bit error rate                        for i=1:1200
    if ((x(i,1)~= X(i,1))||(y(i,1) ~= X(i,1)))
        count=count+1;
    end
end
 ber=count/size(X);

Comment: Dear Rayryeng, is there any way we can use to determine the exact region coordinates. I want to do the ber function. Thank you.

Comment: @KawtherHamad - No, I actually don't know how to calculate the exact region co-ordinates.  As for your other question, I'm answering that in the other post you have written.